# fscanf not reading the file correctly ~ problems with reading of bytes in HEX format

Tags: c, file-io, struct, hex, scanf

I am currently trying to do something that I have done dozens of times in C++, but this is my first time doing it in C.

I have a huge text file with 3 columns: hexNumber    unsignedChar    int

```
adam  38      1
john  39      1
sara  3a      1
frank        3b      0
Christopher        3c      0
kate        3d      0
```

However, like I said the file is huge, and the whitespace between then varies for some reason. I don't know, I didn't make the file. The way I understand it fscanf is delimited by whitespace so any amount should be fine, right?

I'm trying to read it into an array of structs, and here is my code:

```
typedef struct node {
    unsigned char myHex;
    char* myString;
    int myInt;
} node;

void foo(bar* c){

    if( c == NULL )
        return;

    struct node nArr[205] ;

    //read in opcode information
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen( "input.txt" , "r" );

    if ( fp == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Can't open input file file.txt!\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int it = 0;
    while( !feof( fp ) ){

        fscanf( fp , "%s%s%d\n" , nArr[it].myString ,
            &nArr[it].myHex , &nArr[it].myInt );
    }
...
```

However, when I read in it just floods me with whitespace. Print out shows:

```
myHex: 
myInt: 0
myString: (null)
```

Comment: Show us a complete example and also include a head of your input file.

Comment: Is there a maximum length for your `unsigned char` column? Is it really even `unsigned char` or just plain `char`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For reading *hexadecimal **integers***, `%x` format specifier should be used. Also note that the man page of [`fscanf`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fscanf) says about `%x` that: *"pointer must be a pointer to unsigned int."* Thus you should change:

```
while( !feof( fp ) ){

    fscanf( fp , "%s%s%d\n" , nArr[it].myString ,
        &nArr[it].myHex , &nArr[it].myInt );
}
```

to:

```
unsigned int hexVal = 0;
for( ; fscanf(fp , "%s %2x %d\n",
                   nArr[it].myString,
                   &hexVal,
                   &nArr[it].myInt) == 3 ; ++it) {
    nArr[it].myHex = hexVal;
}
```

and in your `struct`, change:

```
char* myString;
```

to

```
char myString[MAX_LEN];
```

where `MAX_LEN` is the maximum length that might appear in your input.

Comment: Give the 'sample' data, even this doesn't make sense. I think we need proper sample data ...

Comment: I'll put the actual data in, sorry.

Comment: Given the new data in the OP's question, should that %u be a %x ? Or even myHex should be larger than a char. Maybe an int.

Comment: @CharlieBurns: Yes it should, I wasn't paying attention to this question anymore :) Yet instead of `%x` it could be `%2x` here :)

Comment: It works aside from the error "warning: format â%xâ expects argument of type âunsigned int *â, but argument 4 has type âunsigned char *â [-Wformat]" That being said, it works fine with %s

Comment: Yeah it's a warning not an error, I assume is just casting. Also, it's not completely right. I didn't realize it but the myString is getting just 1 char, and some times not even the right one.

Comment: @Joshua:  Though it's just a warning, it's a serious one.  Passing a pointer to unsigned char when the %2x tells fscanf to treat it as an int can cause serious problems.  It will likely write outside the char byte in your structure, and it may be why myString is terminating incorrectly.  Either change myHex to int or pass in a pointer to a local int for the %2x argument and then assign the int to myHex after the fscanf call.

Comment: @LihO -- Passing a pointer to a char for a %x argument in a fscanf format string is a significant error.  It will overwrite neighboring data structures and result in erratic program behavior (see Joshua's second-to-last comment).  fscanf != fprintf.  You cannot interchange char and int args.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you've done it as often as you suggest: You are reading a string into an unsigned char - that's not going to fit (in C or C++). You appear to be reading a string into an uninitialized pointer - that's not going to work (in C or C++).

Comment: Do simple mistakes means that I am lying, or simply I am out of practice? I don't appreciate the tone or implication.